# Deploy on Azure from Visual Studio not pushing Controllers folder

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to publish a WebAPI on Azure sites, i followed [this](http://www.brianhprince.com/2012/06/29/hosting-a-webapi-service-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) guide and others like it. When I publish the application from Visual Studio it does not publish the Controllers folder. Is there someone that knows why it does this?
I just create a simple class controller, in local works fine.

Comment: Having the same issue. Clearly the controllers are compiled (otherwise the app wouldn't run!) but I'm having a major problem where I cannot get any changes to the controllers to be reflected in the app when I re-deploy. Seems to me it would help to know just where/what the controllers are in the deployed version.