# Azure: Controller files not updating to azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I have issue regarding updating the controller on example.com (azure hosting).

View files for backend are able to update azure. When we deploy our code to the live from our local server, deployment is done successfully. 
When we update the code to live for both view files and controller files then changes are only made on view files but not on controller files.

Eg: whatever changes we made for view files index.cshtml, they are reflected on the views. But if I make changes on ItemsController then it is not updated to live.

This is the same question which was asked [Deploy on Azure from Visual Studio not pushing Controllers folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416644/deploy-on-azure-from-visual-studio-not-pushing-controllers-folder). But I am not able to get help regarding this.
I also tried to compile on local server then pushed to live server.

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain "when we update the code to live for both view files and controller files..." what exactly do you mean?

Comment: How do you deploy to Azure? Web Deploy, Git sync, copying files?

Comment: @JoeRaio: I mean to say that if I save controller files then it does not save on azure. But when I save cshtml files then it is saving on azure.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze: I deploy via Visual Studio 2013. I publish the files

Comment: @AmukSaxena you have to build they deploy to Azure. Just copying up the controller files will not work.

Comment: @JoeRaio yes i have build the project first. Whenever I make changes then I first run the project then I deploy. Is it correct ?